# Access denied on same domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, jquery

I have a $.ajax that filter some products for me with Get-method. Im also able to filter without ajaxrequest on the same urls.

When i call it from lets http://localhost:xxxx/thePageOfIntressed it works just fine, but if i call it from a postback filtered page lets say http://localhost:xxxx/thePageOfIntressed?category=1 and then press the filterbutton that call the same filter(url) with ajax, i get access denied in IE.
Not in FF, Safari or Chrome, just IE.

Comment: Bump! 
Anyone? there what have i missed?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to cross domain request. E.g. a hardcoded URL is used in ajax request (abc.com), but then you get redirected to www.abc.com on postback. Firing up same ajax request from there will lead to a cross domain call which is not supported in <= IE7.

[Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505%28VS.85%29.aspx) about enabling cross-domain calls on IE6 and IE7.